# If Statement in SQL From Clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to perform an if statement that needs to be done within the From clause of my query. However when I try to do so, I get this error

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.

The query I'm trying to use is the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM
--a few tables with joins
 IF (@a IS NULL OR @a <> '') THEN
    --perform a few more joins
WHERE
--rest of query
```

Is it not possible to perform a case or if statement from the from clause?

Comment: You can not use If statement.

Comment: You can use the If in T-SQL. Search for Dynamic query.

Comment: I'm using SQL Management Studio. Just trying with the case statement at the moment

Comment: Usually, some more consideration will reveal to you that you just need to take these conditions you're trying to put in the `IF` and just *use them directly in the `WHERE` clause* and then combine them with the other parts you're trying to "conditionally include" using an `AND` operator (and possibly moving around other parts of the query and applying other boolean operators)

Comment: Apart from some joins being the same, isn't this a completely different query where you want to select different columns? Then I'd say: write two different queries and be done with it. Or is it the same data you are selecting and only want to use the additional tables in order to limit the records selected?

Comment: @Aiden what are you trying to do? The *tables* are the fundamental building blocks of a query. Adding more tables results in a completely different query, with different results. If you want to create a "dynamic" query, you are doing it wrong. Doing so in a stored procedure doens't make it less of a problem, nor does it offer *any* benefits - no performance, no security, no reusability benefits. Use an ORM to create ad-hoc queries if you want

Answer (score 0):

After realising I can't use a IF Statement and Case would be more appropriate, I've read up and this can only be done dynamically and not from SQL itself.

Comment: No, CASE isn't a solution either. A "dynamic" query is almost always the wrong choice. In this case, it doesn't even make sense. What is the *real* problem you want to solve? Why don't you use an ORM and let *it* create the query to load related objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this on a fundamental level. When you write a query, you already know what data it will return and what tables are needed to get that data.

Now, you can do some switchng between tables in a join by using `outer join`s and statements like `ISNULL()` and `COALESCE()` to see if the joined table actually has the data we're looking for.

The joins could loook like this:

```
declare @checkthis int

select @checkthis = (whatever, resulting in a 1 or a 0)

select *
from tbl_a as a
left outer join tbl_b as b -- tbl_b is optional if @checkthis is 1, else ignore it
    on a.b_foreign_key = b.primary_key and @checkthis = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your joins, you can do something like this...

```
DECLARE @Join AS BIT

SET @Join = 1 --Performs inner join
SET @Join = 0 --ignores join

SELECT *
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
    ON a.Id = b.Id
WHERE
    ((@Join = 0) OR (@Join = 1 AND b.Id IS NOT NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `IF` statement in TSQL has the following syntax:

```
IF [Condition] --NO 'THEN' keyword needed
BEGIN
--myquery
END
ELSE IF [2nd Condition]
BEGIN
--myquery
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--myquery
END
```

[Condition] can be everything that gives you a `TRUE` output like

```
IF DAY(GETDATE()) = 7
BEGIN
PRINT 'IT IS TRUE'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
PRINT 'IT IS FALSE'
END
```

For your specific problem, you can use `CASE` statement, in a `WHERE` clause, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MYTABLE T
INNER JOIN MYTABLE2 T2 ON T2.ID = T1.ID
WHERE T.MYCOLLUMN = CASE
                    WHEN T.MYCOLUMN2 = 0 THEN 'FIRST'
                    WHEN T.MYCOLUMN2 = 1 THEN 'SECOND'
                    ELSE T2.MYCOLUMN
                    END
```